# Implementing Autofac in .NET Core 3 Console Application, injecting IServiceProvider into Config class (not working?)

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, console-application, autofac

This might be a "stupid" question but I'm kind of lost, I'm trying to implement Autofac into a working .NET Core 3.1 Console Application but can't seem to get some things to work.

I have a class named Config.cs that are used at multiple places the console application so I'd like to keep that file so as to not rewrite this implementation.

Here is that file

```
public class Config : IConfig
{
    readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Config(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _config = (IConfiguration)services.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration));
    }

    public string StorageConnectionString => _config["ConnectionStrings:StorageConnectionString"];
    public string SqlConnectionString => _config["ConnectionStrings:SqlConnectionString"];
    public string MongoConnectionString => _config["ConnectionStrings:MongoConnectionString"];
    public string RayGunApiKey => _config["RayGunApiKey"];
    public string ElasticsearchUri => _config["Uris:ElasticsearchUri"];
    public string StatsDUri => _config["Uris:StatsDUri"];

    public string Get(string key) => _config[key];
}
```

This is first used in `Functions.cs` in a TimeTrigger:

```
public class Functions
{
    readonly IConfig _config;

    public Functions(ILogger<Functions> logger, IConfig config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
    }


    public void Run([TimerTrigger("00:00:01", RunOnStartup = true, UseMonitor = true)]TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I start the console application an error is thrown

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DataPurger.IConfig' while attempting to activate 'DataPurger.Functions'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs:line 37
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs:line 32
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0(IFunctionInstanceEx i) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs:line 26
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:line 44
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ParameterHelper.Initialize() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 846
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsyncCore(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 117
```

This injection works without Autofac, but I'm "forced" to implement it since Autofac is used in every other project where I'm working.

Here is the Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RegisterServices();

    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync().Wait();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true,
                reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
        {
            b.AddConsole();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(s =>
        {
            s.AddLogging();
            s.AddOptions();
        })
        .ConfigureWebJobs(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            builder.AddExecutionContextBinding();
            builder.AddTimers();
        })
        .UseConsoleLifetime()
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

static void RegisterServices()
{
    var collection = new ServiceCollection();
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterModule<BaseModule>();
    builder.Populate(collection);

    var container = builder.Build();

    _serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}

public class BaseModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Config>().As<IConfig>().SingleInstance();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, I'm sure there is something missing or that I did not understand correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my sample for ASP .Net core 3.1
in Program.cs I changed

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory()) //<-like yours
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureLogging((context, builder) => builder.AddSerilog())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
```

and I added to Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<QuartzWrapper>().As<IQuartzWrapper>().SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(provider => new JobFactory(provider)).As<IJobFactory>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<JobClass>().As<IJob>().InstancePerDependency();


    }
```

and I used the next packages:

1. Autofac - Version="5.1.2"
2. Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection - Version="6.0.0"

Comment: Thanks for taking yout time to help me out, I have one last question, from where does "ConfigureWebHostDefaults" come from? 

I'm getting: "'IHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureWebHostDefaults' and no accessible extension method 'ConfigureWebHostDefaults' accepting a first argument of type 'IHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I have Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 3.1.2 installed

Comment: I got it to work changing the project sdk to "<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">" , but is it not a bit weird adding the Web SDK to a Console Application?

Comment: Hi, create a new temp project and find code
`dotnet.exe new webapi -f netcoreapp3.1 -n TempCore

Comment: well that is a WebAPI, I'm asking about a Console Application,  and to add "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" to that seems weird to me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to try and check how it works without the module, change

```
 builder.RegisterModule<BaseModule>();
```

to

```
builder.RegisterType<Config>().As<IConfig>().SingleInstance();
```

Comment: I seem you need to make registration after new AutofacServiceProviderFactory(), if you using ASP .Net Core, make it in startup class

Comment: I've been looking at UseWebJobsStartup but the documentation are really lacking on this front.

I've found pretty much complete examples when running ASP.NET (+MVC) but nothing for a .NET Core 3 Console Application and WebJobs.

And what I've found there are only one method in IWebJobsStartup and that is Configure.